# JSON schema - possible to reference multiple schemas from one object?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

Below is an extract from my JSON schema.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "images": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/bits" },
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "identifier": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "bits": {
            "type": "integer",
            "enum": [
                8,
                16,
                32
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As specified, I believe an array of images, where each element consists of a string identifier and an integer whose value can be 8, 16 or 32, would be considered valid JSON data.

This is fine for some of my JSON data.

But what if I want to further constrain the schema such that the integer value can only be 32? How would I do that while still allowing some JSON data to be valid against the original schema?

Is it possible, for example, to reference two schemas in one object, E.g. something like:

```
items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/bits" AND "$ref": "#/definitions/otherSchema"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `allOf` to validate against multiple schemas.

```
{
    "items": {
        "allOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/bits" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/otherSchema" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If otherSchema defines `bits` to be 32, are you saying that the above syntax will give me what I want? Won't it be treated as two separate properties?

Comment: Yes, all schemas in `allOf` apply to the same schema.  In this case, all items in the array must validate against both schemas in `allOf`.  `oneOf`, `anyOf`, and `not` are other keywords that can be used to reference multiple schemas in one.